# Как в Atom убрать добавление пустой строки в конец при сохранении файла?

Tags: atom

Очень мешает при работе с Git. Соответствующую настройку не могу найти.

Comment: Может, [это](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4741) поможет?

Comment: @IgorR. да, whitespace package помог, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла установка пакета "Whitespace package", ссылка на пакет https://github.com/atom/whitespace